# print_once, how blockwise it is working?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I am trying to understand implement a print once function, this code is working fine; 
But I am not able to understand some things:
1) How blockwise this is working? Maybe I am not able to clear it properly, but just want to know, what property of **C** make this happen?

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 
  3 #define _TRACE_
  4 
  5 #ifdef _TRACE_
  6 #define print_once(fmt, ...)            \
  7 ({                                      \
  8      static bool __print_once=false;           \
  9      if(!__print_once)    {               \
 10          __print_once = true;           \
 11          do  {                               \
 12             printf(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);   \
 13         }while(0);                          \
 14      }                                  \
 15 })
 16 #else
 17 #define print_once(fmt, ...)    \
 18 printf("\n");                   
 19 #endif
 20 
 21 void func()
 22 {
 23     print_once("func\n");
 24 }
 25 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 26 {
 27     print_once("test1\n");
 28     //:w
 29     print_once("test22\n");
 30     for(int i =0; i < 2; i++)
 31         print_once("loop\n");
 32     func();
 33     func();
 34     return 0;
 35 }
```

Comment: why `bool` type in C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not standard C, it uses a GCC extension called [statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) (the funny `({...})` syntax). (It's not thread-safe either.)

It works by adding a static boolean at each `print_once` call site (each call site gets its own static flag), initially `false`, which is set to true the first time that piece of code is run (the code only prints if it was indeed `false`). So subsequent executions of the same block of code won't print anything.

Note that the use of the GCC extension is not necessary, and the construction of the macro is strange - it was probably extended from something simpler. This should be C99-compatible (C99 or above required for the [variadic macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro)), and has the `do {...} while(0)` "trick" in the right place:

```
#define print_once(fmt, ...) \
do { static bool flag = false;  \
     if (!flag) { \
       flag = true; \
       printf(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
     } \
} while (0)
```